# Having Errors While Trying to Open a SQLite3 Database

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I'm working in Visual Studio Community 2017, and what I'm trying to do is open and read the information of a database in C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

#include "C:\Users\santiago.corso\Desktop\sqlite-amalgamation-3240000 (1)\sqlite-amalgamation-3240000\sqlite3.h"

bool find_employee(int _id)
{
    bool found = false;
    sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    stringstream ss;

    // create sql statement string
    // if _id is not 0, search for id, otherwise print all IDs
    if (_id) { ss << "select * from employees where id = " << _id << ";"; }
    else { ss << "select * from employees;"; }
    string sql(ss.str());

    //the resulting sql statement
    printf("sql: %s\n", sql.c_str());

    //get link to database object
    if (sqlite3_open("C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("ERROR: can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return found;
    }

    // compile sql statement to binary
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("ERROR: while compiling sql: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return found;
    }

    // execute sql statement, and while there are rows returned, print ID
    int ret_code = 0;
    while ((ret_code = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        printf("TEST: ID = %d\n", sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0));
        found = true;
    }
    if (ret_code != SQLITE_DONE) {
        //this error handling could be done better, but it works
        printf("ERROR: while performing sql: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        printf("ret_code = %d\n", ret_code);
    }

    printf("entry %s\n", found ? "found" : "not found");

    //release resources
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return found;
}
```

The errors that are being returned are from the category Compiler Error C4129.

I cant reach a solution. If you could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please copy the exact error messages from the Output Tab and paste them as text into your question. Few readers will know what a `C4129` error is by memory.. And I mean the Output Tab not the Error List.

Comment: Including the exact error message would help.

Comment: You should escape \ in from your paths. Actually that is the problem `C4129` is a warning about improper escape sequences.. The documentation even mentions the fix: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew69e79d.aspx

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db` - use forward slashes, or double backslashes.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, ever use absolute paths in #includes!
They will prevent the code to correctly compile on anything not your own PC!
(and even on your own PC, it will fail as soon as you rename or move some directories in that path)

Comment: Also, #including files with the name enclosed on quotes won't work.

Comment: I was worry about puting an include with a path, but that is the only way for my visual studio to accept the sqlite3 library, if i put it in all the other ways that exists, visual studio will mark all the sqlite statements as wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I could correct above mistake by puting "\\" in all the parts of the path in sqlite3_open. Beside that, another error poped up about a entry point that must be defined, refering to

```
if (sqlite3_open("C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("ERROR: can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return found;`
```

Also what i want to know is if with this piece of code is enough for opening and reading the database. Im starting with sqlite3 and what i want to do next is exporting its content to an excel file.
Someone recommend me using the exact app for the cause that is native to sqlite3 and is like a cmd.However, i would rather build a script for this purpose instead of using a cmd.